# Vagrant: executable files are not executable

Tags: laravel, phpunit, puppet, laravel-5

I installed vagrant box using https://puphpet.com/
The problem is executable files are not executable:

```
$ ls -la ./vendor/bin/phpunit
-rwxrw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 138 Feb  6 11:07 ./vendor/bin/phpunit*
```

I looked in my `.vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox` in project folder and found there: `"mount_options":["dmode=775","fmode=764"]`.

But this file is generated automatically, so changing it is not a good idea. If I change it, it will be changed back.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Not sure about the file *phpunit* specifically, but in general php files aren't executable. Mine have "-rw-rw-r--" (664) permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may change that with a puppet manifest using the [file-type](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file), especially the [mode-property](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-mode)

```
file {'/project/vendor/bin/phpunit':
  mode => 0777 # read,write,execute for everyone
}
```

Make sure the file exists before running this manifest.
See more on unix file-modes here: http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html